# Removing duplicates in a groupby using apply

Tags: python, duplicates, pandas

I have successfully merged two DataFrames by their temporal nearest neighbours. My current intermediate result looks like:

```
                     merge_key              jd  var2               index  distance  
2010-01-01 00:00:00          0  2455197.500000     0 2010-01-01 00:00:00      0
2010-01-01 00:06:00          0  2455197.500000     0 2010-01-01 00:00:00   -360
2010-01-01 00:12:00          0  2455197.500000     0 2010-01-01 00:00:00   -720
2010-01-01 00:18:00          1  2455197.517361     1 2010-01-01 00:25:00    420
2010-01-01 00:24:00          1  2455197.517361     1 2010-01-01 00:25:00     60
2010-01-01 00:30:00          1  2455197.517361     1 2010-01-01 00:25:00   -300
2010-01-01 00:36:00          1  2455197.517361     1 2010-01-01 00:25:00   -660
2010-01-01 00:42:00          2  2455197.534722     2 2010-01-01 00:50:00    480
2010-01-01 00:48:00          2  2455197.534722     2 2010-01-01 00:50:00    120
2010-01-01 00:54:00          2  2455197.534722     2 2010-01-01 00:50:00   -240
```

In the next step I would like to remove duplicated entries and select only those entries with the min distance. I came up with:

```
df.groupby("merge_key").apply(lambda x: x.ix[np.abs(x['distance']).idxmin()])
```

However, this leads to:

```
          merge_key       jd var2                index distance
merge_key                                                      
0                 0  2455198    0  2010-01-01 00:00:00        0
1                 1  2455198    1  2010-01-01 00:25:00       60
2                 2  2455198    2  2010-01-01 00:50:00      120
```

It seems like the datatype from "jd" has been changed to integer? And I also don't want to have the merge_key as new index.

My desired output actually is:

```
                     merge_key              jd  var2               index  distance  
2010-01-01 00:00:00          0  2455197.500000     0 2010-01-01 00:00:00      0
2010-01-01 00:24:00          1  2455197.517361     1 2010-01-01 00:25:00     60
2010-01-01 00:48:00          2  2455197.534722     2 2010-01-01 00:50:00    120
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this in a slightly simpler method you get the correct result:

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby('merge_key')

In [12]: min_dists = g.distance.apply(lambda x: x.abs().idxmin())

In [13]: min_dists
Out[13]:
merge_key
0            0
1            4
2            8
dtype: int64

In [14]: df.iloc[min_dists]
Out[14]:
                  date  merge_key              jd  var2                index  distance
0  2010-01-01 00:00:00          0  2455197.500000     0  2010-01-01 00:00:00         0
4  2010-01-01 00:24:00          1  2455197.517361     1  2010-01-01 00:25:00        60
8  2010-01-01 00:48:00          2  2455197.534722     2  2010-01-01 00:50:00       120
```

*I think this might be a bug, so perhaps it's worth opening [an issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues).*

Comment: Thank you very much! Just as a side note, you have used consecutive numbers as your index, whereas I have used the dates as index, which means in `min_dist` are not the positions but rather the dates. Then the function `df.ix[min_dists]` has to be used.

Comment: What is the proper syntax for read_table and StringIO to get this data read into df for this example? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, but if you're asking how I got this DataFrame from the question above the answer is `read_clipboard`. :)

Comment: I copied and pasted the table into a string named raw. Then I tried various combinations of  df = pd.read_table(StringIO(raw),header=True,delim_whitespace=True), but I couldn't get it.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: @julieth Ah there is an issue with this specific one since the dates contain a space (which you don't want to use as a delimiter), so I think I used `read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')` (at least two spaces). Otherwise I think your StringIO solution would have also worked.